# Skip clicking on an element in the While loop, when opening a popup with selenium. Problem with While loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, loops, while-loop

This loop scrolls through the list of names on a web page and clicks on each "Add" button next to the name. It works well and correctly

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
i = 1

while i <= limit:
    i = i + 1

    row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{i}]")))
    add = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']"))).click()
    
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row, add)
```

Some buttons create problems, because if I click on them I get an error popup who says I can't add that person to friends. So to solve i created this `close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()` to automatically click "Ok" and close the popup. This code works well and correctly, click correctly on the "Ok" button and close the popup correctly. For information to the reader, if I don't use "close_popup", I get the error `ElementClickInterceptedError`
[image]

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM**:
The problem is when the popup closes,because the button changes from "Cancel Request" to "Add Friend" and you will click again (indefinitely) the latter "Add Friend" which I cannot add. When the popup closes, the loop will always click on the same "Add" button (for example John, the button that gives an error and opens the popup) without ever going forward and never continuing to click on the other buttons. **IMPORTANT: This happens because a certain "Add Friend" button (for example John only), when I click on it, changes to "Cancel Request" and the popup opens. So when I click "Ok" on the popup and it closes, then the "Cancel Request" button will return to "Add Friend".**

**Consequently the script will continue normally and every "Add Friend" button will be clicked, including John's that I can't add and that opens the popup.**

[image]

Consequently, I will indefinitely obtain these operations in the following order:

1. Click on the "Add" button
2. Opening the popup
3. Closing the popup, thanks to the code that clicks on "Ok"
4. Click on the "Add" button again, because when I close the popup the button will change name from "Cancel Request" to "Add"
5. Beginning at infinity of points 1 to 4 above

I would like to skip the click on the "Add Friend" button that blocks the loop (on it or on other successive ones) and opens the popup.

Precisely I would like that if the popup opens, then when the popup closes and returns to the list of people's names, I would like to resume clicking on the "Add Friend" buttons BUT by skipping a single button (1 only, only the one that opens the popup and blocks the loop) and then resuming clicking all the "Add Frriend" buttons again of the first `While`, without skipping any more (unless the same problem occurs with a popup).

So first execute the first While, then execute the second While of the exception (which skips a single button), then return to the first While that continues to click on subsequent buttons (after the jumped button). The purpose of the second While is to call it whenever no "Add Friend" button can be pressed, so its purpose is to skip an "Add Friend" button, then resume clicking subsequent buttons (after skipping a button). This was my idea, but I'm not sure I wrote the second While code well

I tried adding a try and except to the above code. The exception is this (i approach the solution, but there is something wrong):

```
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    print("A button cannot be pressed. You go to the next button ...")

    close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()

    #I skip a button, add only one (1) friend, then stop, and it's back to the main loop for to add and click on all friends
    while True:
        x = x + 2
        row_skip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{x}]")))
        addd_skip = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
        break
```

I had thought of this solution, but I don't know if it is right. I had thought that when I get that popup, it can momentarily start an increment of 2 to skip the button. After this, we close the increment of 2 and this while loop, and then we return to the main while loop. Maybe another solution would be that if the same button is clicked twice, then you have to skip it

How can I solve the problem? Can you suggest a code answer please? Thanks

This is the complete and executable code (including GUI) in case anyone would like to test and help me. **I don't want spam** problems, so I created the possibility to choose for example 5 people to send the request to. This script is for my own study purposes only:

```
    import tkinter as tk                    
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import *
    from time import sleep
    import time
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
    import os
    
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("...")
    root.geometry('530x500')
    root.configure(bg='white')
    
    topbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3b589e', height=42, width = 660)
    topbar.place(x=1, y=1)
    
    secondbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#f0f2f5', height=42, width = 660)
    secondbar.place(x=1, y=40)
    
    #GUI
    label_email = Label(root, text="email", bg='#3b589e', foreground="white")
    label_email.place(x=2, y=10)
    email = tk.Entry(root)
    email.place(x=50, y = 9)
    
    label_password = Label(root, text="password", bg='#3b589e', foreground="white")
    label_password.place(x=260, y = 10)
    password = tk.Entry(root)
    password.place(x=335, y = 9)
    
    link_label = Label(root, text="Post Link", bg='#f0f2f5', foreground="black")
    link_label.place(x=2, y = 52)
    link = tk.Entry(root, width = 50)
    link.place(x=97, y = 50)
    
    link.insert(tk.END, "https:/www.facebook.com/FranzKafkaAuthor/posts/3985338151528881") #example link
    
    number_requests_label = Label(root, text="How many requests to send?", bg='white', foreground="black")
    number_requests_label.place(x=2, y = 110)
    number_requests = tk.Entry(root)
    number_requests.place(x=4, y = 130)
    number_requests.insert(tk.END, "5")
    
    time_label = Label(root, text="Seconds between requests?", bg='white', foreground="black")
    time_label.place(x=2, y = 180)
    time_requests = tk.Entry(root)
    time_requests.place(x=4, y = 200)
    
    
    def start_with_limits(): 
        delay = int(time_requests.get())
        limit = int(number_requests.get())
    
        #Access Facebook
        profile_path = '/usr/bin/firefox/firefox'
    
        options=Options()
        options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
        options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 4)
        options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
        options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
        options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
    
        service = Service('/home/xxxx/bin/geckodriver') ########### CHANGE YOUR PATH
        driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
        driver.set_window_size(600, 990)
        driver.set_window_position(1, 1)
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
    
        #Cookies before login
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]'))).click()
    
        #Login
        username_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
        username_box.send_keys(email.get())
        password_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
        password_box.send_keys(password.get())
    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button'))).click()
    
        # --OPTIONAL
        #Cookies before login (Sometimes it is required while sometimes not
        #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Allow all cookies'] span span"))).click()
    
    
        #Open link
        driver.get(link.get())
    
        #Click on icon-like
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='j1lvzwm4']"))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
    
        #Click su ALL
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
    
        #Scroll down and press "Add friend" buttons
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        i = 1

        try:
    
            while i <= limit:
                i = i + 1
    
                row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{i}]")))
                add = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
                
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row, add)
                time.sleep(delay)
    
                #code for close popup
                #close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()
    
    
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            print("A button cannot be pressed. You go to the next button ...")

            close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()

            #I skip a button, add only one (1) friend, then stop, and it's back to the main loop for to add and click on all friends
            while True:
                x = x + 2
                row_skip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{x}]")))
                addd_skip = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
                break


begin = Button(root, text="Start", bg='#3b589e', foreground='white', width=7, command= start_with_limits)
begin.place(x=1, y=420)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For those who read, is there anyone who can help me? Thanks

Comment: In the end Facebook will suspend your account after you click on enough of those bot-friends.  (been there, done that.)  You'll want to use findElements to get the buttons (webelement references) and keep track of which ones you've clicked by using another array...  but again, you'll have your account suspended before too long.

Comment: @pcalkins I know Facebook will suspend my account. In fact I am building this script for study purposes, to learn python, selenium and automation in general. I will do some tests by setting the addition of a few people and with a large pause, so as not to get suspended by Facebook. I don't want to spam or break rules. In case Facebook suspends me, never mind, that's not a problem. Thanks for the warning :)

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to find some kind of unique id belonging to each user. Then you can create a set of user ids you've already tried to friend. Then, whenever you encounter an "Add Friend" button, you can check the set to see if you have clicked it before. This will ensure you never click the same button twice.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe it's too difficult this way. I just need to skip a button after closing the popup. After some kind users' replies, I noticed that I can skip the button, but the button click does not happen after I skip the button. Can you help me before the bounty runs out?

Comment: The bounty is now over. But rest assured, I read that After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. So even if the bounty expires, you can still help me

Answer (score 0):

since you are changing the site as you scrape the information, your loop wont work the way you want it to work.

i would recomment to first get the information you need and then work trough it:

```py
rows = driver.find_elements(
    by=By.XPATH,
    value=f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])"
)

for row in rows:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row)
    add_button = driver.find_element(
        by=By.XPATH,
        value="//span[text()='Add Friend']"
    )

    add_button.click()
    
    time.sleep(delay)

    try:
        close_popup_button = driver.find_element(
            by=By.XPATH,
            value="//span[text()='Ok']"
        )
        close_popup_button.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

this might not scale very well with content that is dynamically loaded in, but for this purpose it is enough.

if you ever want to add such behavior, i would take a look at sets, which ensure that there are no duplicate values and are somewhat more efficient.

you could then have a loop that does the following until it does not find any new values.

1. find desired elements
2. for each element:

   1. test if element is in set of already clicked elements
   2. if yes, do nothing, if not click on element and add it to the set
3. scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: My problem is not so much the exception catching, but mainly my problem is how to skip a person (and their "Add Friend" button) if i can't add them. So the problem is the second While loop with +2. I don't know if i created it correctly. I need help with this, as i showed in the application pictures. Can you show me the code to skip a person? (in relation to the problem I explained about the change of name in the button)

Comment: You did not understand what I am asking. What you are saying is right, but that is the problem. When I can't add a person as a friend, the script gets stuck on the button of the same person I can't add and tries to add them endlessly. The script clicks on each "Add Friend" button. When I add a person the button changes to "Cancel Request". If I can't add a person, after closing the popup, the button changes back to "Add Friend" and will then try to be clicked (continued in the other comment) –

Comment: (continuation of the previous comment) Consequently the popup will open again, then it will close and the button will have changed its name again from "Cancel Request" to "Add Friend". So the script always block to the same person and doesn't continue, because I can't add it but it will try again and again. For this reason I had created a While loop in the exception with increment +2, so only to skip a person after closing the popup. I'm not sure I wrote the code well, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: i have not quite understood the purpose of the second while loop, as it is called whenever any of  the "add friend" buttons cannot get pressed. maybe what you meant to do is put the try block inside the first while loop. as to how to "skip a person", i thought the for-loop method would fix this issue, since queries all the rows before looping through them, not individual ones while looping through them. you might also use the `continue` keyword to skip to the next iteration of a loop

Comment: The purpose of the second While is to call it whenever no "Add Friend" button can be pressed, so its purpose is to skip an "Add Friend" button, then resume clicking subsequent buttons (after skipping a button). This was my idea, but I'm not sure I wrote the second While code well. Could you help me and edit your answer? (size is running out). Maybe you can give me 2 versions of solutions, both the one I asked for with the second While, and the one you wrote me. But your code gives me an error (I continue in the next comment because there is no space)

Comment: (continuation of the previous comment). The error I get with your code is:     raise exception_class(message,screen,stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[text()='Add Friend'] Stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16 Maybe you can give me 2 versions of solutions (your code and my second while asked in the main question) please?

Comment: then the problem is in this line: `add_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[text()='Add Friend']")`, if the add button is inside the row element you could try to do something like this: `row.find_element()`. the issue of my code is the inaccuarate xpath value, since i don't know how the site is layed out